# How to remove gray color in Dired mode?

Tags: dired, faces, customize-face

Linux Mint ,
Emacs 27.2

Dired, Dired+, Dired-k

As a result here is the dired mode view

[image: Dired mode]

As you can see, the names of files:

- to.do.org
- to.do.org_archive_2017
- to.do.org_archive_2019

are gray. Can I remove this gray color?

Answer (score 1):

Put your cursor on a char with that gray foreground, and use `C-u C-x =`. The `*Help*` tells you (near the bottom) what face(s) are used there.

Then use `M-x customize-face` to customize the face(s) to be as you like.

Comment: After set this: (dired-k-human-readable t) the gray color is gone

Comment: If that's an answer, please consider submitting as an answer (perhaps with some explanation). You can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

After set this: `(dired-k-human-readable t)` the gray color is gone

```
Use human readable size format option.
```

[image]

Nice.

P.S.

Here another settings: color depends on file size

[image: color depends on file size]

Here another settings: color depends on file date.
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a brief explanation of what this does?

Comment: @Tyler I update my answer. As you can see no more gray file names.

Comment: Why were they gray before? I presume that `dired-k-human-readable` is some variable defined in `dired-k`: what does it mean? what is its doc string? (I don't have `dired-k` installed, so it would be nice if you added that kind of explanation, so that people like me  can find out what is going on without having to install `dired-k` themselves).

Comment: @NickD I was updated my answer.

Comment: What does `human readable size format option` have to do with colors?

Comment: @NickD yes. In dired-k you can set color of column "date" depends on file size.